# Need help changing my website's name / address

Tags: apache, ip-address

this might sound a bit amateur-ish but I'm in a bit of a situation here.
So I created myself a website and managed to get it working on localhost, I tried port forwarding ports 80,443 but nothing helped, So next thing I'm googling around and I read about ngrok and it actually worked. Got it working on a long randomly generated domain but the problem is that I want to use the one that I have from no-ip.com. How can I do that please? I'm very lost here.
Software being used: Xampp (Apache,MySQL)

I've reserved a DHCP ip-address for my PC in my router's settings, hopefully that helps? I don't know. Help me internet.

Comment: @MosheKatz That could probably be an answer.

Comment: Oh, that might explain it. Is there a way to see if they are blocking my connection?

Comment: As an aside to any actual answer, you probably don't want to be hosting a public website on your home network. Any hacker that compromises your site will likely be able to access all the other devices in your home too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of possible reasons that this might not work. Here are a few of them.

### Your ISP

Even if you have port forwarding set up properly on your router, it is still possible that you cannot do what you want.

First, many ISPs block serving websites from residential internet connections. Connections to port 80/443 will never even reach your router. You might try experimenting by forwarding a different port number (such as `8000` instead of `80`) to see if the traffic can get through on that port. (However, that will not work as a practical solution since your users will not know to use an alternate port and your ISP can choose to terminate your service if you are violating the terms of your agreement.)

Second, due to the exhaustion of public IPv4 addresses, some ISPs are implementing Carrier-Grade NAT (CGNAT, a.k.a. Large-Scale NAT - LSN). Instead of giving your router a public IP address, they give your router a private IP address inside their network. Once again, connections to port 80/443 (or any other port for that matter) will never reach you. You can check if you are behind CGNAT by going to your router's setting and finding the public IP address, then going to https://whatsmyip.com/ and seeing if it is the same or different. (In theory, you should be able to tell that you have CGNAT if your router's IP address is between `100.64.0.0` - `100.127.255.255`, but in practice some ISPs use other private network ranges too, such as `10.0.0.0` - `10.255.255.255`.)

The reason Ngrok works for you is because Ngrok opens a tunnel from your computer to their cloud servers and sends the traffic through that tunnel.

### DNS

You mentioned in the comments that you have the DNS set to resolve the private IP of your computer. That certainly will not allow users on the public internet to get to your site, because they cannot connect to your address.

However, you also mentioned in the comments that if you change the DNS to point to your public IP, it doesn't work from either inside or outside. This could mean your problem is one of the ISP issues described above. It could also mean that your router does not support Hairpin-NAT (a.k.a. NAT Reflection), which is how the router would be able to redirect local traffic back to the local server instead of trying to send it out over the internet.

### Firewall

Your computer's firewall can look at the source IP address of the incoming traffic, and it might be set not to allow external access to your web server. **DO NOT DISABLE YOUR FIREWALL to try to get around this.** Instead, you need to add a specific exception to the firewall rules to allow the incoming traffic. How you do this will depend on your operating system.